# How to write and read an object which contains pointer variables into a file in c++?Help me with the following code

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, fstream

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>

struct node     /*node for info along with pointer variable*/
{
   char name[20];
   int n;
   node *next;
};

class info
{
   node *head,*tail;
   public:
   info();
   void insert();
   void display();
};

info::info()
{
   head=NULL;
   tail=NULL;
}

void info::insert()
{
   node *New;
   New=new node;
   cout<<"\nEnter the name and integer:";
   cin>>New->name>>New->n;
   New->next=NULL;
   if(head==NULL)
      head=tail=New;
   else
   {
      tail->next=New;
      tail=tail->next;
   }
}

void info::display()
{
   node *temp;
   temp=head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
   {
      cout<<"\nName:"<<temp->name<<" integer "<<temp->n;
      temp=temp->next;
   }
}

int main()
{
   info list1;
   clrscr();
   int ch;
   do
   {
      cout<<"\n1.insert 2.display 3.exit";
      cout<<"\nEnter choice:";
      cin>>ch;
      switch(ch)
      {
         case 1:
            cout<<"\nEnter the file name:";
            char *fn1;
            cin>>fn1;
            ofstream out(fn1,ios::binary);
            list1.insert();
            out.write((char *)&list1,sizeof(list1));
            out.close();
            break;
         case 2:
            cout<<"\nEnter the file name:";
            char *fn2;
            cin>>fn2;
            ifstream in(fn2,ios::binary);
            in.read((char*)&list1,sizeof(list1));
            list1.display();
            in.close();
            break;
      }
   }while(ch!=3);
   return 0;
}
```

In the above code I have used "*head" and "*tail" pointer variables for building queue .The problem is how can I write the info into a file and read
the info from the file?
The code run it doesn't run properly.

Comment: research topic - persistent storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to help you along.

**Save and restore one object**

```
node n1;
strcpy(n1.name, "Sai Charan");
n1.n = 10;
```

Think of the things you need to save to a file to be able restore the data from the file back to another `node`.

**Save and restore a `vector<node>`**

```
std::vector<node> nodes;

// Add couple of node objects to node.
```

Think of the things you need to save to a file to be able restore the data from the file back to another `vector<node>`.

**Now apply the same logic to `info`**

That should give you enough background to be able to save and restore the linked list of `node`s in an `info` object.

Comment: But I'm using turbo c++ compiler and I don't have any idea about "vector" concept.So, is there any other way to do so?

Comment: @SaiCharan, you can create a standard of array of `node` objects - `node nodes[10];` - and use it instead of using a `std::vector<node> nodes;`.